# Missing Project Template after installing ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have downloaded the ASP.NET MVC 2 Release version (using Web Platform Installer) as well as the downloading the file directly from the link in WPI. No error messages are reported after the install.

When I go into Visual Web Developer and select Create New project I only the project reference to ASP.NET MVC version 1.0 and not version 2 (for clarity I have all the other project types, this is just in reference to the MVC projects).

I have restarted, uninstalled and restarted and installed my PC multiple times and it still won't play.

When clicking add a reference I can see the MVC.dll version 2.0.0.0 and add that no problem, but cannot manually upgrade the project since the ProjectTypeGuid used is not recognized.

For reference I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 on Windows XP. ASP.NET MVC version 1.0 is working fine and without issue.

Hope someone else can help.

DNH

Comment: WAG--make sure you're targeting the correct version of the framework in your project... Not sure which mvc2 requires, but try 3.5 and see if the templates reappear.  If not, target the next lower version and see if they appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed MVC2 (VWD Express) on 3 computers now and 2 of them (Windows 7 and XP) have done this.  I fixed both of them by uninstalling MVC1, MVC2 and VWD, then reinstalling via the Web Platform Installer.  MVC1 is gone from WPI by the way. You can still download it from MS though.  Could be just luck, but like I said, this worked twice for me.